# Javascript on save SugarCRM

Tags: php, javascript, sugarcrm

I am trying to create a popup in sugarcrm for the notes module. When a user clicks "Save Note" I want to validate that the field notes_c is not empty. If it is empty I would like an error to popup and say that the note is empty. They can either cancel or save anyways. Below is the code I have added but am not able to get the popup to display.

I added the buttons to custom/modules/Notes/metadata/editviewdefs.php

```
  array (
    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    'headerTpl' => 'modules/Notes/tpls/EditViewHeader.tpl',
    'buttons' => array(
                        array('customCode'=>'<input id="samples_transfer_save" type="submit" value="Save Note" name="button" onclick="this.form.action.value=\'Save\'; return (check_save() && check_form(\'EditView\'));"  class="button" accesskey="S" title="Save [Alt+S]"/>&nbsp;'),
                        'CANCEL',
       ),
  ),
  'includes'=> array('file'=>'custom/modules/Notes/checksave.js'),
```

The buttons do show up and the form does save it just does not display an error if that box is empty.

Here is the JS file called checksave.js

```
function check_save() {
              if(document.getElementById('notes_c').value == '') {
                      document.getElementById('warning').innerHTML = 'Warning: No Public Notes Entered';
                      $j("#warning").fadeIn("slow");
                      setTimeout('$j("#warning").fadeOut("slow");',20000);
                      return false;
              }else {
                      return true;
              }
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to go to Studio, edit the notes_c field, and check the "Required Field" checkbox. This will take care of the validation for you.

If you insist on adding your own js to validate then you can keep the default buttons but in your js file override the onsubmit function.

```
document.EditView.onsubmit = check_save;
```

Answer (score 1):

To add custom scripts in SugarCRM I do this:

in logic_hook.php

```
<?php

$hook_version = 1;
$hook_array = Array();

$hook_array['after_ui_frame'] = Array();
$hook_array['after_ui_frame'][] = Array(1, 'JQuery', 'custom/modules/Accounts/custom_code/customscripts.php','JQuery', 'JQuery'); 

?>
```

after in jquery class file

```
<?php

class JQuery{

    function JQuery($event, $arguments){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="custom/modules/Accounts/custom_code/jmask.js"></script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="custom/modules/Accounts/custom_code/scripts.js"></script>';           
    }

}
?>
```

and create normal JS file called scripts and import jmask.